# Why does it keep saying "Housing Invalid" for the room on the left?

Tags: terraria

[image]

How do I get the room on the left to be a valid house for an NPC?

Comment: Specifically, "The floor cannot be only wood platform, there must be a place for the NPC to stand without him standing on wood platforms. Make sure the room is big enough to be considered a proper house as well".

Comment: It has to do with either low light level or wood platform floor.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things which are causing your housing to become invalid.

[image: screen cap of problem]

Firstly, you can't use a platform as your only flooring - NPC's will want some kind of solid ground to stand on.

Secondly, because the platform isn't a valid floor, it's counting the circled area as part of your house. The whole area behind the house needs to have a back wall - this cannot be a dirt wall either, it needs to be made of wood or stone or somesuch.

Comment: *Some* of the floor can be platform, but there must be some solid ground, too.